# Using longest word in context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I came across with the following word

> **antidisestablishmentarianism**

How do you pronounce this word, meaning and how can i use this word in a context?

Thanks

Comment: The only context it's usually found in is hardly one that fits with the site's aims of addressing the interests and concerns of 'linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts'. You can find far longer words if you try a tiny bit harder.

Comment: Any dictionary will give you a pronunciation; many online dictionaries even provide audio clips in a generic English and a generic American accent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Wikipedia, the pronunciation of [*antidisestablishmentarianism*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antidisestablishmentarianism)  is:

- UK: /ˌæn.ti.dɪz.ɪs.tæb.lɪʃ.mənˈtɛə.rɪə.nɪ.z(ə)m/
- US: /ˌæn.taɪˌdɪs.ɛsˌtæb.lɪʃ.məntˈɛ.ri.ənˌɪ.zm/

Here’s a [YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WUrx92VoMq8) featuring the word’s pronunciation, and here’s an example sentence:

> Those who opposed disestablishmentarians, and there were many,
>   particularly in Ireland and Wales, were thus supporters of
>   antidisestablishmentarianism.